# Sync dynamodb into redshift table with kenisis firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I've found a tutorial for how to get item level changes into s3 from dynambo via kinsis firehose [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/deliver-dynamodb-records-to-amazon-s3-using-kinesis-data-streams-and-kinesis-data-firehose-with-aws-cdk.html)
but how do I get these into a redshift table? If an item is updated, it will create a new record for it and post to s3, so is there a tutorial or guidance on how to take these item level changes and read them into a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinesis Firehose has [multiple destinations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/create-destination.html) that you can choose from. S3 is only one of them, and Redshift is another.

You can use the [following configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/create-destination.html#create-destination-redshift) to set up Redshift as the destination.